# My views.py is returning null from django admin object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I would really appreciate some help on this because I'm completely stuck. I've started up a simple django app (trying to make an instagram clone). However, when I try to display the post objects (which I created in the django admin page) nothing is displayed in index.html, so I tried printing out the objects in the views.py and it's returning to me an empty query set. I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong and why I can't access the objects? When I print out the username I am able to get that, but then nothing for both post and stream objects. Please I'm so stuck any advice would be appreciated.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from post.models import post, stream

@login_required
# we are getting all of the string objects that are created for the user
def index(request): 
    user = request.user 
    print(user)
    posts = stream.objects.filter(user=user)
    print(posts)
    group_ids = []
    
    #then looping through and getting post id to a list 
    for posted in posts: 
        group_ids.append(posted.post_id)
    print(group_ids)

    #then filtering them so that you can display it in the index 
    #selecting a specific post by id 
    post_items = post.objects.filter(id__in=group_ids).all().order_by('-date')

    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = {'post_items' : post_items}
    

    return(HttpResponse(template.render(context, request)))
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid
# Create your models here.

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.urls import reverse 


def user_directory_path(instance,filename): 
    # this file is going to be uploaded to the MEDIA_ROOT /user(id)/filename
    return('user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id,filename))

class tag(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 80, verbose_name = 'tag')
    slug = models.SlugField(null = False, unique = True)

    class Meta: 
        verbose_name = 'tag'
        verbose_name_plural = 'tags'
    # for when people click on the tags we can give them a url for that  
    # def get_absolute_url(self): 
    #     return(reverse('tags', args = [self,slug]))

    def __str__(self): 
        return(self.title)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug: 
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) 
        return(super().save(*args, **kwargs))

class post(models.Model): 
    # will create a long id for each post 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = user_directory_path, verbose_name= 'image', null = True)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length = 2000, verbose_name = 'caption')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(tag, related_name='tags')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField()


    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('postdetails', args=[str(self.id)])
    
    # def __str__(self): 
    #     return(self.user.username)



class follow(models.Model): 
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='follower')
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='following')


class stream(models.Model): 
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='stream_following')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()

    def add_post(sender, instance,*args, **kwargs): 
        # here we are filtering all the users that are following you 
        post = instance
        user = post.user
        followers = follow.objects.all().filter(following=user)
        
        for follower in followers: 
            streams = stream(post=post, user=follower.follower, date = post.date, following = user)
            streams.save()
    
post_save.connect(stream.add_post, sender=post)
```

output from print statements

```
user
<QuerySet []>
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't an issue with the code, but the way that I was creating posts in the admin panel. So because you can only view posts from users that you are following, the posts that I was creating weren't showing up. So I had to create another user, and follow that user, then have the new user post something. Then the post shows up in the page!